# I keep getting invalid syntax on my python3 code

Tags: python-3.x

I am converting given time in second to hour, minute, and second. For example, `3662`  can be printed `1hour 1minute 2seconds`.

```
def convert_seconds(time):
   second = time%60.0
   minute = int((time%3600)/60.0)
   hour = int(time/3600)
   return '%s hour%s, %s minute%s, %s second%s', % (hour, 's' if hour!=1 else '',
                                                    minute, 's' if minute!=1 else '',
                                                    second, 's' if second!=1 else '')
```

There is `invalide syntax` at my last format code `%`. Why do I keep getting this error? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extra comma (`,`) character after the format string. Should be:

```
return '%s hour%s, %s minute%s, %s second%s' % (hour, 's' if hour!=1 else '',
                                                minute, 's' if minute!=1 else '',
                                                second, 's' if second!=1 else '')
```